# News Scraper always get's second latest article instead of latest article

Tags: python, web-scraping, rss

I made a news Scraper that gets the RSS feed of a website called "Phoronix" and saves it in a text file. But for some reason it gets the second latest article instead of latest article.

Here's the code:

```
import feedparser
import time

def Log():
    f = open("Logs/phoronixdb.txt", "a")
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("\n" + entry.published)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("\n" + entry.title)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("\n" + entry.summary)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write("\n" + entry.link)
    f.close()

def CheckDate():
    f2 = open("db/phoronixlastdate.txt", "r")
    date = f2.read()
    if date == entry.published:
        f2.close()
    else:
        Log()
        f2.close()
        f2 = open("db/phoronixlastdate.txt", "w")
        f2.write(entry.published)
        f2.close()

while True:
    NewsFeed = feedparser.parse("https://www.phoronix.com/rss.php")
    entry = NewsFeed.entries[1]
    CheckDate()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but do you need to access element [0]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that this

```
entry = NewsFeed.entries[1]
```

should be

```
entry = NewsFeed.entries[0]
```

This is because i believe the entries return a list of articles as an array, where starting index(0) corresponds to the first article and so on.